# Regex Pattern to Remove Custom Markers

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to figure out a regex that would strip a set of custom markers from a character string. For example, if I have the string,

```
s = "{\n \"graph\": \"#! graph1 !#\",\n\"element\": \"#! 
    document.getElementById('x_axis1') !#\",\n\"orientation\": \"bottom\" \n}"
```

I want the output to be

```
"{\n \"graph\":  graph1 ,\n\"element\":  document.getElementById('x_axis1') 
 ,\n\"orientation\": \"bottom\" \n}"
```

I tried the following code

```
gsub('\"#!([^!].*)!#\"', "\\1", s)
```

But it only removes the first set of markers. I would really appreciate if anyone can point me to a regex that would strip all the custom markers.

Comment: perl=TRUE seems to help, but your example isn't valid R syntax (too many quotes)

Comment: It is the result of converting an R object to JSON. I am essentially trying to pass some arguments as objects rather than strings, which is why the markers.

Comment: what i'm trying to say is that if i copy and paste s into the console, it returns an error as it is not a valid string ('x_axis1' is the problem). If I replace those single quotes by double, then perl=TRUE in your regex seems to work fine.

Comment: `perl=TRUE` seems to work. I am trying a few more test cases. Can you post your comment as an answer.

Comment: ah. okay. i should have just pasted the json output directly, rather than using `cat` to print it out. my apologies.

Comment: i'll let you pick the better answers below, as I don't actually understand why perl=TRUE works; it was just a wild guess from ?gsub

Comment: @baptiste thought you may be interested - with extended regular expressions (default) `.` will match `\n`, whereas in Perl `.` does *not* match `\n`, which is why `perl=TRUE` works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
gsub("#!(.*?)!#", "\\1", s)
```

As long as you don't accept nested "blocks" of `#!...!#` (e.g., `#! hello #! world !# goodbye !#` as one occurrence) and you don't need to detect "unmatched" blocks, that should do everything you need.

If you do need nested matching, you'll need to build a proper parser instead of using regular expressions. (This isn't hard; it's merely worth noting that you can't use regular expressions to detect arbitrarily nested blocks.)

Comment: there are no nested blocks. your `gsub` is removing everything including the text between the markers, which i want to retain.

Comment: Right. Fixed, @Ramath. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 4):

It's your regex. The `.*` in `[^!].*` is matching everything from `graph.1 !#....` onwards (including the newlines).

Try (changed `[^!].*` to `[^!]*`):

```
gsub('\"#!([^!]*)!#\"', "\\1", s)
#> cat(gsub('\"#!([^!]*)!#\"', "\\1", s))
#{
#   "graph":  graph.1 ,
#   "element":  document.getElementById('x_axis1') ,
#   "orientation": "bottom" 
#}>
```

Comment: nice. that seems to work too. i am just testing a few more use cases. i wonder why `perl=TRUE` also worked. any thoughts?

Comment: I think it is because Perl does not include `\n` in the `.`, whereas extended regex (the default when perl=T is not specified) does

Comment: Note - this will fail if you have a '!' embedded in the string, like `"foo": "#! bar! !#"`. If cannot guarantee that '!' will not be in the string, I suggest @sigpwned's answer (non-greedy match).

Comment: i am accepting @sigpwned answer although i liked yours too. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use two `gsub`s:

```
gsub('!#"', "", gsub('"#!', "", s))
```

Comment: That is nice, but I only want to remove occurrences that follow the pattern `!#...#!`.